# Strange Behaviour Using Scala Parallel Collections and setParallelism

Tags: scala, parallel-processing

I recently found out about Parallel Collection in Scala 2.9 and was excited to see that the degree of parallelism can be set using collection.parallel.ForkJoinTasks.defaultForkJoinPool.setParallelism.

However when I tried an experiment of adding two vectors of size one million each , I find

- Using parallel collection with parallelism set to 64 is as fast as sequential (Shown in results).
- Increasing setParallelism seems to increase performance in a non-linear way. I would have atleast expected monotonic behaviour (That is performance should not degrade if I increase parallelism)

Can some one explain why this is happening

```
  object examplePar extends App{    

  val Rnd = new Random()
  val numSims = 1

  val x = for(j <- 1 to 1000000) yield Rnd.nextDouble()
  val y = for(j <- 1 to 1000000) yield Rnd.nextDouble()

  val parInt = List(1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256)    
  var avg:Double = 0.0
  var currTime:Long = 0

  for(j <- parInt){
    collection.parallel.ForkJoinTasks.defaultForkJoinPool.setParallelism(j)
    avg = 0.0
    for (k <- 1 to numSims){
      currTime = System.currentTimeMillis()    
      (x zip y).par.map(x => x._1 + x._2)
      avg += (System.currentTimeMillis() - currTime)
    }
    println("Average Time to execute with Parallelism set to " + j.toString + " = "+ (avg/numSims).toString + "ms")    
  }

  currTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
  (x zip y).map(x => x._1 + x._2)
  println("Time to execute using Sequential = " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - currTime).toString + "ms")        
}
```

The results on running the example using Scala 2.9.1 and a four core processor is

```
Average Time to execute with Parallelism set to 1 = 1047.0ms
Average Time to execute with Parallelism set to 2 = 594.0ms
Average Time to execute with Parallelism set to 4 = 672.0ms
Average Time to execute with Parallelism set to 8 = 343.0ms
Average Time to execute with Parallelism set to 16 = 375.0ms
Average Time to execute with Parallelism set to 32 = 391.0ms
Average Time to execute with Parallelism set to 64 = 406.0ms
Average Time to execute with Parallelism set to 128 = 813.0ms
Average Time to execute with Parallelism set to 256 = 469.0ms
Time to execute using Sequential = 406ms
```

Though these results are for one run, they are consistent when averaged over more runs

Comment: If you try to set more parallelism than you have available processors, you'll have these things run serial to each other, but still pay the parallelism tax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parallelism does not come free. It requires extra cycles to split the problem into smaller chunks, organize everything, and synchronize the result.

*You can picture this as calling all your friends to help you move, waiting for them to get there, helping you load the truck, then taking them out to lunch, and finally, getting on with your task.*

In your test case you are adding two doubles, which is a trivial exercise and takes so little time that overhead from parallelization is greater than simply doing the task in a one thread.

*Again, the analogy would be to call all your friends to help you move 3 suitcases. It would take you half a day to get rid of them, while you could finish by yourself in minutes.*

To get any benefit from parallelization your task has to be complicated enough to warrant the extra overhead. Try doing some expensive calculations, for example a formula involving a mix of 5-10 trigonometric and logarithmic functions.

Comment: Thanks. I liked your analogies :-). I replaced the function evaluated with one that was more sophisticated one (Using a series of nested Trignometric functions evaluated in a loop). I am now able to see a 2.5x speedup w.r.t to the non-parallel implementation. But still the performance degradations is unexpected and disappointing when increasing the parallelisms :-( But as you said it could be that the overhead increases with increasing parallelism.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest studying and using the `scala.testing.Benchmark` trait to benchmark snippets of code. You have to take JIT, GC and other things into account when benchmarking on the JVM - see [this paper](http://buytaert.net/files/oopsla07-georges.pdf). In short, you have to do each of the runs in the separate JVM after doing a couple of warm-up runs.

Also, note that the `(x zip y)` part does not occur in parallel, because `x` and `y` are not yet parallel - the `zip` is done sequentially. Next, I would suggest turning `x` and `y` into arrays (`toArray`) and then calling `par` - this will ensure that the benchmark uses parallel arrays, rather than parallel vectors (which are slower for transformer methods such as `zip` and `map`).

Comment: Thanks, Being primarily a statistician I liked the rigor in the paper, I will follow it for a more rigorous evaluation of Scala's parallelism